# How to export the message section of a select query (JARED ZAGELBAUM RESTORE for SQL Server Express)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I am working with SQL Server 2012-17 Express and trying to set up Jared Zagelbaum's restore script that is used in addition to Ola's database backup and command log.

The issue I am running into is that the script requires that you create a job that output's the results of a stored procedure into a .txt file. The weird thing about it is that it outputs the **Messages** part and not the **Results** part.

I can't create a job with it being Express so I have to schedule a task in Windows to fire off a `.bat` file that says execute this `.sql` script. I am fine with this process but what I am running into is exporting the 'Messages' section as that is what needs to be exported to the `.txt` file.

I have tried `BCP` but it just seems to export the results which are 0, so it creates a blank `.txt` file with the correct name and address. Anyone have any idea how to get the messages exported in SQL Server Express by using T-SQL. Is there some system table I can query? I am trying to automate this process so copy/paste or right click and save file as aren't what I am looking for.

Please let me know if I need to elaborate more on something. Thanks

Comment: I think something like this should work but won't let me use 'exec'  and gives error 'Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]BCP host-files must contain at least one column'                                                                                                                                                 


DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(8000);
SET @stmt='BCP "exec RestoreCommand" QUERYOUT "C:\sqlscripts\test.txt" -c -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + DB_NAME();
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt;

Comment: Problem is when I use a temp table or even holding table to hold the results and then try to export those with BCP, it no longer has the generated messages that the script generates.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server Developer Edition has all of the features SQL Server offers, but is limited in the size of the database allowed. Is that not an option?

Comment: Hey @UnhandledExcepSean Down the road, potentionally but I'm coming into an environment of hundreds of DB and some are on Express.  I was kind of hoping that there was some sort of system temp table somebody knew about that stores messages that are thrown?  Really what I'm trying to do is either 1) capture and export the messages section of the results OR 2) figure out how to turn it into select statements that return results as I could export those using BCP.    Jared code https://jaredzagelbaum.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/automated-restore-script-output-for-ola-hallengrens-maintenance-solution/

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to accomplish what I wanted (which was capturing the output of the file, just like when you run it in SSMS) by starting command prompt and then using `sqlcmd` function.  The final export script looked like this:  `sqlcmd -S servernamehere -d databasenamehere -E -Q "exec RestoreCommand" -s "," -o "C:\whereyouwantittogoandwhatyouwantittobenamed.txt"`

Documentation found here:  https://datatofish.com/how-to-export-sql-query-results-to-text-file/

Then just put that in a .bat file and create a schedule to run it as often as you want the scripts generated.